# How to sort lines in a text file by last name in python?

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

Beginner here!

So I have a .txt file that is arranged like this;

(first name) (last name) (Age) (City)
(first name) (last name) (Age) (City)
(first name) (last name) (Age) (City)
(first name) (last name) (Age) (City)
(first name) (last name) (Age) (City)

What I want to do is create a function in python to keep it like its arranged now but sort it alphabetically by last name.
Thankful for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic is straight forward for this.

- Read each line into a dictionary with the last name as the key
- Sort the keys
- Output the lines based on key (last name)

Try this code:

```
ss = '''
(fname3) (lname8) (12) (NY)
(fname2) (lname7) (34) (PA)
(fname4) (lname9) (11) (SF)
(fname1) (lname4) (40) (LA)
(fname5) (lname5) (5)  (LV)
'''.strip()

with open ('names.txt','w') as f: f.write(ss)  # write data file

#########################

with open('names.txt') as f:
   lines = f.readlines()

d = {ln.split()[1]:ln.strip() for ln in lines}  # use last name (col 2) as key

keysort = sorted([k for k in d])  # sort keys

for k in keysort:
   print(d[k])
```

Output

```
(fname1) (lname4) (40) (LA)
(fname5) (lname5) (5)  (LV)
(fname2) (lname7) (34) (PA)
(fname3) (lname8) (12) (NY)
(fname4) (lname9) (11) (SF)
```

Note that you can also split all the lines into arrays then sort the lines based on array index. The csv module can help with this.

Answer (score 1):

Read the lines, call the python function `.sort` or `sorted`, then write the lines. This requires the whole file to fit in memory, which might be a problem if the file's size is more than a few GB.

Function `.sort` accepts an optional argument `key` which can be used to specify the sorting criterion; in our case, we can split the line into words, and sort according to the second word.

Note that this logic only works if we assume that first names and last names are all exactly one-word long, which is far from realistic.

```py
input_filename = 'filename.txt'
output_filename = 'filename.txt'

with open(input_filename, 'r') as f:
  l = [line for line in f if line.strip()]

l.sort(key=lambda line:line.split()[1])

with open(output_filename, 'w') as f:
  for line in l:
    f.write(line)
```

Note: I used different variables for the filenames of the input and output files, but this will work even if you use the same filename for input and output.

The condition `if line.strip()` when reading filters out empty lines; this avoids `l.sort` complaining that it can't find the family name on an empty line.

Since we sort according to family name and nothing else, and since python's `.sort` is **stable**, this preserves relative order for people who have the same family name.